# Is there a way to search inside a message using Gmail API?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I have thousands of email. I need to search whether any of the message contains the text "Hello world" or any other regular expression. How can I achieve this using Gmail API?

Answer (score 0):

The [Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list)-request supports a custom query parameter that you can use. This parameter works just the same as the search input field in the regular [Gmail Client](https://mail.google.com/).

```
q = Hello world

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=Hello+world
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "14f9826d5e0811ee",
   "threadId": "14f9826d5e0811ee"
  }
 ],
 "resultSizeEstimate": 1
}
```